# combining two arraylist into a single linked list in one go

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I am getting an list as shown below

```
 List<String> tr = newdatamap.get("B1").getRef();
 List<String> tr2 = newdatamap.get("B1").getMS();
```

now as you can see that we have two arraylists but I want to store it contents into single a list itself. Something like that:

```
List<String> tr = newdatamap.get("B1").getTradeRef() + newdatamap.get("B1").getTMS();
```

but it is showing an error. Please advise how we can combine them into a single linked list.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to produce a new `List` with the content of `tr` and `tr2`, then you can try with:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(){{ addAll(tr); addAll(tr2); }};
```

If you want to *append* `t2` to `tr`, then you can do:

```
List<String> tr = newdatamap.get("B1").getRef().addAll(newdatamap.get("B1").getMS());
```

Comment: `addAll` returns a boolean so you can't assign the result back to a List.